# SerialPort has no method 'list'

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

I have a very simple script to just the available serial ports and then connect to one, write a char and put the response on the console. [CODE HERE](http://pastebin.com/bDZG4cMe)

In my scripts directory I did:

```
#npm install serialport
#npm list
 /home/uminded/Programming/nodeJS/test
 └─┬ serialport@1.0.8
   ├── async@0.1.18
     etc...
#node test.js
   spits out entire serialport.js to command line then...
 has no method 'list'
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/uminded/Programming/nodeJS/test/test.js:4:12)
 at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
 at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
 at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

The serialport.js script does have an export for SerialPort.list why can it not find it?

Also what program do you guys use for writing and debugging node related js?

Answer (score 16):

`list` is a [property of the `serialport` module](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/blob/master/serialport.js#L292), and not of `serialport.SerialPort`. Replace the first lines like this:

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var util = require("util"), repl = require("repl");

serialport.list(function (err, ports) {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    console.log(port.comName);
    console.log(port.pnpId);
    console.log(port.manufacturer);
  });
});
```